# How to prevent Firefox reloading tabs (even one clicked on)

Tags: firefox, tabs, reload, startup

Seriously, is there any way to tell Firefox NOT to reload tabs after start?

I know I can check "Don't load tabs until selected" in Options window, but this only stops reloading tabs automatically and will still reload tab I click on - I do NOT want that!

**I want to reload every tab myself.**

The reason is that sometimes I have multiple tabs with Adminers' SQL command textarea which gets cleared on reload. You surely get how *happy* I am everytime I have to remind the commands.

I tried googling for any extensions or about:config options but nothing do what I want. Am I the only one wanting this?

I submitted the bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=900494

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to disable loading of clicked tabs. But, you can try for instance [Work Offline addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/work-offline/) that allows you easily switching Firefox to offline mode. Firefox loads clicked tab from its cache in offline mode and it could preserve your textareas.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I just had this issue myself and perhaps this answer will help other users. I went into *about:config* and searched for the setting *browser.sessionstore.max_resumed_crashes* and changed that from default 1 to 0.

Comment: This did not do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firefox' `about:config` (via the address bar), click "accept the risk", then type `accessibility.blockautorefresh` in the search bar and toggle that setting to true.

Edit: restart of FF is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, but this doesn't work on Firefox 103.0. I tried to set this to `true`, then restart FF, the tabs refreshed on boot, then restart again but the tabs refreshed again.

Comment: Strange! For me it worked in FF 103.0 
I wonder if any of the other configs play a role here.
For instance, I have

browser.sessionstore.restore_hidden_tabs =>  false; 
browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand =>  true; 
browser.sessionstore.restore_pinned_tabs_on_demand => false;
browser.sessionstore.restore_tabs_lazily =>  true; 
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash => true; 
browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once =>  false;
browser.sessionstore.resuming_after_os_restart => false

Comment: I have the same values as you do. :(